# Using Observables for streams in Angular and subscribing to them in another class what is the best way to approach delivery to the DOM/template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular2-observables

In my app component I am using the constructor to bring in a service. `MyService` As a reference this is a test service for data streaming from an IOT device. What I am wondering is whether using this method I have below or which is taking an Input data1 and setting that as an Array. Or, I am reading about Observables and streams and binding directly to them in the DOM/template with Ng-If-as.

The below dom with the ngFor is fine but when I utilize the ngIf as async pipe that fails with the error below.

`Property 'i' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.`

```js
 <ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data1">
      <!-- <li *ngIf="item.isValid"></li> -->
      <li ngIf="_myService | async as i; else loading">
        {{ i }} 
      </li>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
  <div #loading>Waiting...</div>
```

Below is what I have in regards to the appcomponent setup. I have
`` app = construct myService => set to property => serve `<ng-container *ngFor="let item of data1"> `` That works but it is because I am setting the data to another property and having to setup that property.

```js
 @Input() data1: Array<IContentObj> = [];

  constructor(public _myService: MyService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this._myService.getServerSentEvent('http://localhost:8888/sse').subscribe((data: IContentObj) => {
      // console.log('DATA ', data);
      
      return this.data1.push({
        id: data.id,
        content: data.content,
        type: data.type,
        time_stamp: data.time_stamp,
        data: data.data
      });
      // // this.someObs = data;
      console.log('BLUE ', this.data1);
    });
  }
```

[Here is from the angular docs as storing a conditional result in a variable](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-a-conditional-result-in-a-variable)

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-if-as',
  template: `
    <button (click)="nextUser()">Next User</button>
    <br>
    <div *ngIf="userObservable | async as user; else loading">
      Hello {{user.last}}, {{user.first}}!
    </div>
    <ng-template #loading let-user>Waiting... (user is {{user|json}})</ng-template>
`
})
export class NgIfAs {
  userObservable = new Subject<{first: string, last: string}>();
  first = ['John', 'Mike', 'Mary', 'Bob'];
  firstIndex = 0;
  last = ['Smith', 'Novotny', 'Angular'];
  lastIndex = 0;
```

The issue I see from my code above is that I am not directly referencing the variable. But it is async and it will be undefined until data streams in. So for me, I want access to my `data` from the subscription (that is constructed in from the service) to act as a stream in the ngifas per the Angular docs.

> Storing a conditional result in a variable
> You might want to show a set of properties from the same object. If you are waiting for asynchronous data, the object can be undefined. In this case, you can use ngIf and store the result of the condition in a local variable as shown in the following example.

In summary, how do I get the proper Observable effectively as a async pipe ng-if-as on my DOM/template from a pulled in service?

What I was thinking is that I could setup an observable proper on the component I am worried about and stream the async `data` into that Observable and just serve that up to the dom.
But something about that seems like code smell to me as what is the point of the service then?

There is also [Ngrx Let Component](https://ngrx.io/guide/component/let) but I am not even getting the above to work so not sure what the advantage of this is over the form.

Comment: `(_myService | async) as i`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski so not ngif? I have the above code emitting that error. I think it is because it is not an observable directly but rather a service class. Or do you mean the ( ... )

Comment: 2 pissibilities. first is that your pipe is trying to send the ENTIRE myService. you only want to send the observable from that service. do ```(_myService.someObservable | async) as i; else loading``` instead. alternatively, it could be that your subscribe isn't sending data properly. the @Input on a variable means that the PARENT COMPONENT of this component will be sending that variable (normally within the parent components html). remove @input from data1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I get the proper Observable effectively as a async pipe ng-if-as on my DOM/template from a pulled in service?

You must apply the `async` pipe to an observable, not the entire service.  You *could* do this:

```html
<li ngIf="_myService.getServerSentEvent(...) | async as i; else loading">
```

But usually, you'd define an observable property and use that in the template:

```
serverEvents$ = this._myService.getServerSentEvent(...);
```

```html
<li ngIf="serverEvents$ | async as i; else loading">
```

---

I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to achieve, but it looks like you receive some initial data from an `@Input()` and then you want to append new messages from the server as they are received.

If that's that case you could do something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let event of initialEvents"> {{ event.id}} </li>
  <li *ngFor="serverEvents$ | async as event"> {{ event.id }} </li>
</ul>
```

One thing to note is that `serverEvents$` needs to be an array, so we can use the [`scan`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/scan) operator to create an observable that collects the server emissions into an array and emits the entire array each time a new items is received:

```js
@Input() initialEvents: IContentObj[];

serverEvents$: Observable<IContentObj[]> = this._myService.getServerSentEvent(...).pipe(
    scan((all, event) => all.concat(event), [] as IContentObj[])
);
```

---

I'd probably lean towards having a single observable array that includes both the initial items and the newly received ones:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let event of events$ | async"> {{ event.id }} </li>
</ul>
```

To create a single observable, we can use `startWith` to provide the initial value (passed via the `@Input()`):

```js
@Input() initialEvents: IContentObj[];

private serverEvent$: Observable<IContentObj> = this._myService.getServerSentEvent(...);

public events$: Observable<IContentObj[]>;

constructor(private_myService: MyService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    events$ = this.serverEvents$.pipe(
        startWith(this.initialEvents),
        scan((all, event) => all.concat(event), [] as IContentObj[])
    );
}
```

---

All that said, it may end up being cleaner to pass an `IContentObj[]` via the `@Input()` and let the parent component be in charge of doing the work to build up that collection.  Essentially, moving the definition of `events$` into the parent and passing it with `async` pipe to the child:

```html
<child [events]="events$ | async"></child>
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir. That is ultra clear and clears it up.

Comment: Do you know about the ngrx let component does that make it better or is this ngif good enough?

Comment: Hey just want to let you know that I really appreciate this answer. I haven't coded hard core in angular in a few years. This answer got me right on track. I did some pretty cool things. One thing I did that was cool on top of your answer was the use of "tap" so I could set another property for "error" and "close" which are also stream results. I also did some cool browser detection stuff so the tabs and blur of clicking off will close the other streams. Again, thanks!